# highcharts - does not create with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to chart created after an event like click a button, but chart does not created after clicking the button.

in sample there are 2 divs. `container1` and `container2`, 
`container1` render partialView in razor and works fine and chart created, but `container2` suppose to contains a chart after `Change Data` button clicked, it call an action via AJAX that renders same partialView as shown in `container1` but does not work!

where I'm wrong?

action called and server responding and there is no error in console, this is after button click:

[image]

Index.cshtml(View)

```
<button id="changeDataButton">Change Data</button>

<div id="container1">
    @{
        Random random = new Random();
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/chartPartialView.cshtml", new ChartModel()
        {
            CategoriesStackBar = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" },
            Series = new List<Series>()
                {
                    new ColumnSeries()
                    {
                        Name = "A",
                        Data = new List<ColumnSeriesData>()
                        {
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                        },
                    }
                },
            Id = "chart",
        });
    }
</div>

<div id="container2">

</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#changeDataButton').click(function (event) {
                console.log('change data button clicked');
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: '/Home/UpdateChart',
                    success: function (partialView) {
                        console.log("success");
                        console.log(partialView);
                        $('#container2').innerHTML = (partialView);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

(Controller)

```
    public ActionResult UpdateChart()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        PartialViewResult partialViewResult = PartialView("~/Views/Shared/chartPartialView.cshtml", new ChartModel()
        {
            CategoriesStackBar = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" },
            Series = new List<Series>()
                {
                    new ColumnSeries()
                    {
                        Name = "A",
                        Data = new List<ColumnSeriesData>()
                        {
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                            new ColumnSeriesData()
                            {
                                Y = random.Next(100),
                            },
                        },
                        Id = "dynamicChart",
                    }
                }
        });
        return partialViewResult;
    }
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What happens ? Is the server requested ? Does it answer ? Any error in the console ?

Comment: @SergeK.question updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `innerHTML` directly on a jQuery object, you'll have to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) :

```
$('#container2').html(partialView);
```

Comment: no error! I guess scripts not executing after receive, if you look at screenshot you'll see some scripts

Comment: Well I read your code too fast. Your script won't run as stated by the [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) (see the green note).

Comment: so, how to execute scripts?